# Update bigquery value based on partition by row number

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-update

I have a table in which I have records on the wrong date. I want to update them to be the day before for "snapshot_date". I have written the query to select the  values I want to update the date for, but I don't know how to write the update query to change it to the previous day.

See screenshot

[image]

Query to select problematic records

```
Select * FROM(
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Period, User_Struct) rn 
     FROM `XXX.YYY.TABLE` 
     where Snapshot_Date = '2021-10-04'
     order by Period, User_Struct, Num_Active_Users asc
) where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`DATE_SUB`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions) you may get the previous day i.e.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(cast('2021-10-04' as DATE), interval '1' day)
```

will give `2021-10-03`.

You may try the following using [Big Query Update Statement Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement)

```sql
UPDATE 
    `XXX.YYY.TABLE` t0
SET
    t0.Snapshot_Date = DATE_SUB(t2.Snapshot_Date, interval '1' day)
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT 
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Period, User_Struct) rn 
        FROM 
            `XXX.YYY.TABLE` 
        WHERE
             Snapshot_Date = '2021-10-04'
        ORDER BY -- recommend removing order by here and use recommendation below for row_number
             Period, User_Struct, Num_Active_Users asc
    ) t1 
    WHERE rn = 1
)  t2
WHERE
   t0.Snapshot_Date = t2.Snapshot_Date AND -- include other columns to match/join subquery with main table on
```

You should also specify how your rows should be ordered when using `ROW_NUMBER` eg

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Period, User_Struct ORDER BY Num_Active_Users asc)
```

if this generates the same/desired results.

Let me know if this works for you.